# MediaWiki on MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, mediawiki

I've been doing some digging on running mediawiki on sql server instead of MySQL, but haven't come across any concrete information. All of our servers are running SQL Server so I'd like to stick with that. I've tried Screwturn wiki, which is an ASP.NET wiki implementation using SQL Server, but I'm not terribly happy with the editing interface, and would really like to get MediaWiki up and running. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 2):

I had been looking at doing the same thing recently, but decided that I would be better off setting up MySQL just to serve Mediawiki. Consider the advantages of each:

**MySQL**

- Is a supported database, so you'll get better answers if something goes wrong.
- Will definitely be supported by patches and upgrades.
- Is very well tested through Wikipedia. You're less likely to see "strange" behaviour.
- Easy setup and widely available documentation - whereas you will probably need to carefully document the tricks you use to get MediaWiki working with MSSQL.

**SQL Server**

- Can leverage existing backup methods in a homogeneous environment
- Can assign permissions based on Active Directory

It took me less than an hour to configure a virtual machine with a LAMP stack, then install and configure MediaWiki. Backup is a crontab that dumps the MySQL database onto the fileserver. Your mileage may vary, but you'll probably end up saving a lot of time by going with the supported solution.

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible.

https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=9767

There's a patch, but I have not confirmed it working (or tried it). This might work for a while, just be very careful about patching.